# Am I missing something here ? XD TrimRight does not seem to want to work

Tags: trim, cstring

Ok, here is the small portion of code to demonstrate:

```
CString txt = _T("Hello World");
CString txt2 = txt;
txt2.TrimRight('W');
AfxMessageBox(txt2);
```

The output is "Hello World".

What am I not getting right ?

Comment: does TrimRight return a new string? Should it be `txt2 = txt2.TrimRight('W');`?

Comment: I also tried that..., same result

Comment: that and `CString txt2 = txt.TrimRight('W')` directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `txt2.TrimRight('W');` removes all characters 'W' from the right side of the string. Since "Hello World" does not end in 'W' nothing is trimmed at all.

Comment: I thought it removed all characters to the right of the string after the W, I get the difference now thanks